# Trying to understand strange behaviour of Dockerfile during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I cannot understand why docker is doing what it does.

My host directory structure goes like this (simplified by leaving out directories)

```
|
-----Server
|       |
|       --------
|              |
|              -----api
-----Client
|
package.json
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.18 AS node-build
WORKDIR /app
RUN --mount=target=.,rw --mount=type=cache,target=~.npm pwd && ls -la && cat .env && npm install --omit=dev
...
```

The output from `docker build` run at the root of the root of the directory structure,  and in particular the pwd and ls command is

```
/app                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8198 Oct 30 22:10 api
```

Although I'm in the root of the directory structure the ls command appears as though I'm in the source subdirectory.  I can't understand how it knows there is a subdirectory and why it operates the ls as though its already been copied to `/app` in the container.

How, why?